# native-методы в Java

Tags: java, c++, jni, native, keyword

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня появился вопрос примерно следующего характера. Всё никак не могу понять, где именно хранится реализация native-методов, которые поставляются со стандартным API от Oracle (раньше Sun Microsystems). Позволю себе привести конкретный пример! У нас есть класс System из пакета java.lang. Когда мы впервые обращаемся к этому классу, к примеру, при вызове метода System.out.println(), то происходит инициализация статических полей этого класса (то бишь, выполнются статические инициализаторы и код, который находится внутри блоков статической инициализации). Так вот, первым делом выполняется следующий код:

```
static {
    registerNatives();
}
```

где registerNatives(), это статический native-метод. Насколько мне известно, то реализация таких методов описана на других языках программирования, таких как, C/C++, FORTRAN и языки ассемблера. Но где посмотреть сам код, мне неизвестно, а хотелось бы это сделать! Я по природе очень дотошный человек, хочу знать, как всё устроено! Буду благодарен всем за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация хранится в самой JVM, а код можно посмотреть в её [исходниках](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/hotspot/file/5ab7a67bc155/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l3058).